# Restaurar git reset después de git add

Tags: git

Tenía una web hecha y quería añadirla a git.

El caso es que hice `git init`, `git remote add origin ...`, `git add -A` y me di cuenta que tenía node_modules añadido, con lo que quise deshacer el `git add` para añadir un `.gitignore` pero para esto hice un `git reset --hard` asi que ahora no veo ningún archivo de la web. ¿Habría alguna forma de restaurar el `git reset --hard` para dejarlo todo como estaba?

Si hago `git fsck --lost-found` obtengo esto:

```
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (master)
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
notice: No default references
missing tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
dangling blob ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a
```

He hecho un `git checkout 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904 -- .` pero me tira esto:

```
error: pathspec './' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En general, no podrás recuperar el estado de tu carpeta de trabajo si no habías hecho *commits* de los cambios. Al haber hecho `git add`, los cambios estaban en el `index`, pero un `git reset --hard` borra también el `index` (no así uno `--soft`).

Pero aún hay esperanza. Aunque no podrás recuperar los ficheros, puedes aún ver sus contenidos. Una vez has hecho `git fsck --lost-found`, los "dangling blobs" que te reporte son los contenidos de los ficheros desaparecidos.

En tu caso puedes hacer:

```
git show ce013625030ba8dba906f756967f9e9ca394464a
```

y debería mostrarte el contenido del fichero. Puedes redireccionar la salida para guardarlo. El nombre del fichero debes recordarlo tú. Me extraña no obstante que reporte un único *dangling blob*. Por tu pregunta entiendo que tenías muchos ficheros...

Comment: Pues me toca revisar 7993 ficheros... vaya tela :(

Comment: Wow... ¿y cómo es que sólo te reporta un _dangling blob_? ¿Qué hay en él? Están en un solo blob los 7993 ficheros? ¿O es que te había reportado muchos más blobs?

Comment: Lo que puse en el ejemplo era una réplica que hice del problema con un solo archivo y hacer pruebas ahí para no liarla mas, pero en el listado de lo realmente perdido están todos los dangling separados. Muchas Gracias